# Count the number of times (frequency) a string occurs

Tags: r, count, word-frequency

I have a column in my dataframe as follows

```
   Col1
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Center for Animal Control, Division of Hypertension, Department of Medicine
   Department of Surgery, Division of Primary Care, Center for Animal Control
   Department of Internal Medicine, Division of Hypertension, Center for Animal Control
```

How do I count the number of strings that occur that is separated by a comma, in other words what I am trying to accomplish is something like this below

```
    Affiliation                         Freq
    ------------------------------------------
    Center for Animal Control           3
    Division of Hypertension            2
    Department of Medicine              1
    Department of Surgery               1
    Division of Primary Care            1
    Department of Internal Medicine     1
```

Could someone help me to figure this out?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far, and what is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach. Also substitute `'\n'` with a comma since you have some new lines in your text.

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = rep("Center for Animal Control, Division of Hypertension, Department of Medicine, Department of Surgery, Division of Primary Care, Center for Animal Control, Department of Internal Medicine, Division of Hypertension, Center for Animal Control", 1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$col1 <- gsub('\\n', ', ', df$col1)
as.data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(df$col1, ', '))))
```

Output as follows (on original data):

```
                             Var1 Freq
1       Center for Animal Control    3
2 Department of Internal Medicine    1
3          Department of Medicine    1
4           Department of Surgery    1
5        Division of Hypertension    2
6        Division of Primary Care    1
```

Comment: What is `gsub('\\n', ',', df$col1)` doing? `\n` as a linebreak doesn't need a second escape like `\\n`

Comment: Actually, this doesn't give the correct result - "Center for Animal Control" is repeated twice. You need to account for spaces either side of the comma like: `data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$col1), "\\s*,\\s*"))))`

Comment: Bro, your code fails in case col1 has value "Division of Hypertension, Department of Medicine, Center for Animal Control" as in your answer, a separate Affiliation field will be created for ` Center for Animal Control`

Comment: Edited to fix the extra space issue.

Comment: `\\n` is still unnecessary, and it would much safer to use `\\s*` to represent "0 spaces or more" instead of `" "` alone.

Comment: Thank you for the `',\\s*'`. Got it and agree. As for the `'\n'`, when I paste the provided test and not `gsub` it, I get `Center for Animal Control\nDepartment of Internal Medicine` as one of the 'tokens.' Hence my fix for it.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: `Center for Animal Control, Division of Hypertension, Department of Medicine` is value for row 1, `Department of Surgery, Division of Primary Care, Center for Animal Control` for row 2 and so on.

`df` is the data frame.

```
aff_val <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(df$col1,",")))

ans <- data.frame(table(aff_val))

colnames(ans)[1] <- 'Affiliation'
```

Comment: This is the same answer as below.

Comment: @Gopala Please see the code carefully. There is absolutely no need to do the gsub thing as  done in your answer in line 2 if the assumption made by me is correct. It's different in that way.

Comment: In the input data, there is a new line that separates the departments (not comma) - example Department of Medicine and Department of Surgery. They won't be picked up by `strsplit` on a comma.

Comment: @Gopala I think you are not able to understand the assumption. I have assumed that the data is stored row wise in the data frame. You are assuming it to be in a single row. I am assuming that the records are stored in different rows of the data frame.

Comment: Understood. Good solution!

Answer (score 1):

I use `scan` and `trimws` for these text processing tasks.

```
inp <- "    Center for Animal Control, Division of Hypertension, Department of Medicine
    Department of Surgery, Division of Primary Care, Center for Animal Control
    Department of Internal Medicine, Division of Hypertension, Center for Animal Control"

> table( trimws(scan(text=inp, what="", sep=",")))
Read 9 items

      Center for Animal Control Department of Internal Medicine 
                              3                               1 
         Department of Medicine           Department of Surgery 
                              1                               1 
       Division of Hypertension        Division of Primary Care 
                              2                               1
```

Can also wrap as.data.frame around that result:

```
> as.data.frame(table(  trimws(scan(text=inp, what="", sep=","))))
Read 9 items
                             Var1 Freq
1       Center for Animal Control    3
2 Department of Internal Medicine    1
3          Department of Medicine    1
4           Department of Surgery    1
5        Division of Hypertension    2
6        Division of Primary Care    1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
a<-"Center for Animal Control, Division of Hypertension, Department of Medicine
Department of Surgery, Division of Primary Care, Center for Animal Control
Department of Internal Medicine, Division of Hypertension, Center for Animal Control"
con<-textConnection(a)
tbl<-read.table(con,sep=",")
vec<-str_trim(unlist(tbl))
as.data.frame(table(vec))
```

The answer is

```
1       Center for Animal Control    3
2 Department of Internal Medicine    1
3          Department of Medicine    1
4           Department of Surgery    1
5        Division of Hypertension    2
6        Division of Primary Care    1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "Center for Animal Control, Division of Hypertension, Department of Medicine
Department of Surgery, Division of Primary Care, Center for Animal Control
Department of Internal Medicine, Division of Hypertension, Center for Animal Control"

library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data_frame(text = text) %>%
  mutate(line = text %>% stri_split_fixed("\n") ) %>%
  unnest(line) %>%
  mutate(phrase = line %>% stri_split_fixed(", ") ) %>%
  unnest(phrase) %>%
  count(phrase)
```