# r string parsing challenge

Tags: r, string, transform

I am dealing with a column that contains strings as follows

```
       Col1
       ------------------------------------------------------------------
       Department of Mechanical Engineering, Department of Computer Science
       Division of Advanced Machining, Center for Mining and Metallurgy
       Department of Aerospace, Center for Science and Delivery
```

What I am trying to do is separate strings containing the words starting with either, Department or Divison or Center until comma(,) the final output should look like this

```
       Dept_Mechanical_Eng   Dept_Computer_Science   Div_Adv_Machining   Cntr_Mining_Metallurgy   Dept_Aerospace  Cntr_Science_Delivery
       1                     1                       0                    0                        0              0
       0                     0                       1                    1                        0              0
       0                     0                       1                    1                        1              1
```

I have butchered the actual names just for aesthetic purpose in the expected output. Any help on parsing this string is much appreciated.

Comment: `library(splitstackshape); cSplit_e(mydf, "Col1", ",", type = "character", drop = TRUE, fill = 0)`. Also look at `strsplit` + `mtabulate` from "qdapTools".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to a question I just did tabulating another text example. Are you in the same class as the questioner here? [Count the number of times (frequency) a string occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877940/count-the-number-of-times-frequency-a-string-occurs)

```
 inp <- "Department of Mechanical Engineering, Department of Computer Science
        Division of Advanced Machining, Center for Mining and Metallurgy
        Department of Aerospace, Center for Science and Delivery"
 inp2 <- factor(scan(text=inp,what="",sep=","))
#Read 6 items
 inp3 <- readLines(textConnection(inp))

as.data.frame( setNames( lapply(levels(inp2), function(ll) as.numeric(grepl(ll, inp3) ) ), trimws(levels(inp2) )) )
  Department.of.Aerospace Division.of.Advanced.Machining
1                       0                              0
2                       0                              1
3                       1                              0
  Center.for.Mining.and.Metallurgy Center.for.Science.and.Delivery
1                                0                               0
2                                1                               0
3                                0                               1
  Department.of.Computer.Science Department.of.Mechanical.Engineering
1                              1                                    1
2                              0                                    0
3                              0                                    0
```